# How to display two card views without Recycler-view in Android studio?

Tags: java, android

How can I display two card views without Recycler-view in Android studio?

Comment: This question is not fit for StackOverflow, this question also shows a very very poor research effort and will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I have not implemented a `RecyclerView`, however I have replicated two rows in a linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:background="#303030">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:background="@drawable/vector_red"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSub" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtSub"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:id="@+id/cv1"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:background="#303030">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:background="@drawable/vector_red"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSub" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/txtSub"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtMain"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/person_photo" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Take into consideration, you might have to change view id's

Lets explain this a bit further:

The root layout of this is a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation, which means elements inside the LinearLayout will be placed one after the other vertically. That is the gist of it.

If you want more control on how the items are placed, consider using a RelativeLayout at root.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout that will hold the cards. This way of approaching it provides flexibility in the future when you are required to add or remove cards.

> preference.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="@color/white_alpha"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:title="@string/your_title">

         <include layout="@layout/first_card"/>

         <include layout="@layout/second_card"/>

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Next create your two card layouts:

> first.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                                tools:showIn="@layout/preference">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:text="@string/your_text"
        android:textColor="@color/color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

> second.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                                tools:showIn="@layout/preference">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="15dp"
        android:text="@string/your_text"
        android:textColor="@color/color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```